# Twitter streaming formatting JSON Output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter

Maybe you can help me. This following python code retrieves Twitter Streaming data and stops when 1000 tweet data are got. It works but returns the fields "created_at, screen_name, and text" separated by tab. Instead I'd like to get the data in JSON format. How can I set the code in order to get the data formatted in JSON?

```
# Import the necessary package to process data in JSON format
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

# Import the necessary methods from "twitter" library
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API


CONSUMER_KEY = '7pWHWtYlXM9ayJfUKv2F8v84B'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'Dfcx10Px77Ggn0qGbCHc4TZC7M2IHsXpqk9CaGiCLzcr9VMX5n'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '245080367-zuLrIbxblOnocashgku9dsmDKgy3R7uU0VCTIRDx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'wCx5ufD9Zft46hVjieLdv0af7p9DxUTsPgge9Zm2qelR9'

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

# Initiate the connection to Twitter Streaming API
twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=oauth)

# Get a sample of the public data following through Twitter
#iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample()

iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track="Euro2016", language="fr") 

tweet_count = 1000 
for tweet in iterator:
    tweet_count -= 1


    print (tweet['created_at'],"\t",tweet['user']['screen_name'],"\t",tweet['geo'], "\t",tweet['text'])


    if tweet_count <= 0:
        break
```

Comment: *"It works but returns the fields "created_at, screen_name, and text" separated by tab"* - and? That's exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd like the output data in JSON format

Comment: So change the code to do that, but don't be surprised when it does exactly what it's written to. Do you have a question? Maybe read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can import `tweepy` (you need to install it first with pip) and override the `listener class` to be able to output the data in json format. Here is an example:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

#Listener Class Override
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try: 
            tweet = json.loads(data)
            with open('your_data.json', 'a') as my_file:
                json.dump(tweet, my_file)
        except BaseException:
            print('Error')
            pass

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(statuses)

my_listener=listener()
twitterStream = Stream(oauth, my_listener)  #Inizialize Stream object
```

You can read more about `tweepy` here: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html